# Gracefully close chrome on shutdown

Tags: chrome, shutdown, logout

I would like to close chrome before shutdown/restart/logout

The reason for this is to have chrome restore the last session automtically and without displaying the restore button

I tried putting a script in `/etc/rc0.d/` like so

`sudo vim /etc/rc0.d/K01close-chrome`

```
killall -15 chrome
```

`sudo chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/K01close-chrome`

I also tried putting the same code in `~/.logout` which worked well when I logout but not in the case of a shutdown or restart

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`killall chrome --wait` worked for me